# Search specific value in a range from another range in power BI where search value can be in any position

Tags: powerbi

I have two columns Description which consists of Names with some scrap value and another column with proper Resource name, but the sequence of the resource name is not correct. For e.g in data for John January Actuals it shows Andy. I want to add another column and it should show Johan instead of Andy for John January Actulas.

| Description | Resource name |
| --- | --- |
| John January Actuals | Andy |
| Andy Feb Forecast | John |
| Mickey Jan & Feb Act | Shelly |

The result I want is

| Description | Resource name |
| --- | --- |
| John January Actuals | John |
| Andy Feb Forecast | Andy |
| Mickey Jan & Feb Act | Mickey |

Comment: Where is this coming from? Is this a result of a PowerQuery query?

Comment: no table 1 is source from excel file. the resource names are not in sequence if compared to description.